# render a placeholder image in place the images in those posts who don’t have an actual image location

Tags: reactjs

**this is the code i currently have - it shows posts from a subreddit - when i run the code in react, there are a few posts where images are not rendered since there is no data
for the thumbnail image - i want to render a thumbnail place holder image - i think i need to make another component and call it ? but i am not sure**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
    const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
    const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/popular.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.data.children);
            setPosts(result.data.children);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("You have an error.");
        });
}, []);

const handleSearch = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    if (event.target.name === "searchFor") {
        setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
    }
    if (event.target.name === "searchType") {
        setChecked(event.target.checked);
    }
};

//The searchedPosts variable below contains the posts after the filter is run on the subRData array
    //TO start with it returns the posts whose title include the search term
    //Modify it to return posts based on if the checkbox is checked or not
    //If the box is checked then return the post based on a title search
    //if the box is not checked then return the post based on if the number of comments on it are greater than the provided number in the search box.
    const searchedPosts = posts.filter(function (post) {
        if (checked) {
            return post.data.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        }

        if (post.data.num_comments >= searchTerm) {
            return post;
        }
    });

    //subreddit gets rendered right here
    //maybe insert below the seperate component

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Reddit Data Display </h1>
            <hr />
            <Search term={searchTerm} doSearch={handleSearch} searchType={checked} />
            <hr/>
            <SubRPostDisplay posts={searchedPosts} />
            <hr />
            <Totals posts={searchedPosts} />
        </div>
    );
}
function Search(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h4>Search based on Title/Comments </h4>
            <input
                name="searchFor"
                type="text"
                id="search"
                value={props.term}
                onChange={props.doSearch}
            />
            <input
                name="searchType"
                className="ml-3 mr-3"
                type="checkbox"
                id="searchType"
                value={props.searchType}
                onChange={props.doSearch}
            />{" "}
            (check for title search)
        </div>
    );
}

function SubRPostDisplay(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return props.posts.map(function (post) {
        return (
            <div id="post" data-key={post.data.created}>
                <img src={post.data.thumbnail} alt={post.data.title} />
                <span id="postLink">
                    <a href={post.data.url}>{post.data.title}</a>
                </span>
                <button
                    id="commentNum"
                    type="button"
                    className="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2"
                >
                    Comments{" "}
                    <span className="badge badge-light">{post.data.num_comments}</span>
                </button>
                <button id="upsNum" type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-2">
                    Ups <span className="badge badge-light">{post.data.ups}</span>
                </button>

                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    });
}

function Totals(props) {
    let numcomments = 0;
    let numups = 0;
    props.posts.forEach(function (post) {
        numcomments += post.data.num_comments;
        numups += post.data.ups;
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info mr-2">
                Total number of Comments{" "}
                <span className="badge badge-light">{numcomments}</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-info mr-2">
                Total number of Ups <span className="badge badge-light">{numups}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you want exactly, but you should be able to just add a fallback image url to the image source. Something like this:

```js
<img
  src={post.data.thumbnail || 'https://link.to/fallback.png'}
  alt={post.data.title}
/>
```